# Behavior on sending an integer (not from heap) as an argument to the thread

Tags: c, multithreading, arguments, pthreads, parameter-passing

I want to create threads with different index values ​​from the same function. I always send the variables to threads, from the heap. But I do not want to send from the heap, because I want to send a different variable here to know the indexes of all of them; in this case if I send from the heap, the index value may change in others without being stored yet.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Myarg{
    int index;
};

void *foo(void *arg)
{
    struct Myarg *a = (struct Myarg* ) arg;
    printf("\nfoo%d executed", a->index);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid[6];

    struct Myarg arg;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        arg.index = i;
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, foo, &arg) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nerror!");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(tid[i], NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nerror!");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a couple of outputs from this code:

```
foo1 executed
foo2 executed
foo3 executed
foo4 executed
foo5 executed
foo5 executed

foo1 executed
foo4 executed
foo3 executed
foo5 executed
foo5 executed
foo2 executed
```

I share this code just to show my intention. Here is an example of the various results I expected:

```
foo1 executed
foo4 executed
foo3 executed
foo5 executed
foo6 executed
foo2 executed
```

I think I can realize this intention by taking the integer from the heap and creating six argument variables different for all of them. But I wonder exactly what happened here? Or can this aim be achieved without creating 6 different variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the address of the *same* struct to *each* of your threads.  This means you have a race condition regarding what value the struct happens to contain when each thread reads it.

The simplest solution is to have an array of structs and pass a different array element to each one.

```
struct Myarg arg[6];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    arg[i].index = i;
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, foo, &arg[i]) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nerror!");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Also, you're not using the heap anywhere in your code because you never call any of the `malloc` family of functions.  All of the relevant variables are locals which (on most implementations) live on the stack.

Alternately, you can allocate a structure for each thread on the heap and pass that in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    struct Myarg *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
    arg->index = i;
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, foo, arg) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nerror!");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

And the thread will be responsible for freeing the memory:

```
struct Myarg *a = arg;
printf("\nfoo%d executed", a->index);
free(a);
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Comment: so, this 6 arg variables live on the stack of a main thread. does this pose any problem? Isn't there an obligation to be in heap? because as far as I know they don't share their stacks.

Comment: @quasimodo Each thread will have its own stack, but that doesn't stop them from accessing variables that live elsewhere as long as the lifetime of those variables is still active.